# Font-weight not working on specif areas of a website

Tags: css, fonts

On [this website](https://www.qconcursos.com/questoes-de-concursos/questoes/0e98c403-37), I'm unable to remove the bold property from the bold text (text starts with "Conforme o art. 43...").

What is most intriguing is that the `font-weight` command below applies normally to all parts of the referred site, except for the bold part.

I'm using the following code in Stylebot (Chrome Extension):

```
    div {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 14.49px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: auto;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

How can I get this done? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please let me know if this is what you are looking for.

```
div > * {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 14.49px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: auto;
    font-weight: 300;
}

or


* {
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 14.49px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: auto;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Edit: Maybe this is more what you are looking for->

```
.q-question-enunciation > span{
    font-family: Open Sans;
    font-size: 14.49px;
    text-align: justify;
    text-justify: auto;
    font-weight: 300;
}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer, I missed part of your question.

Comment: I'm not sure how to use the extra code you provided. Should I copy and paste ".q-question-enunciation > span{

font-weight:none;
}"? If that's the case, it didn't work

Comment: .q-question-enunciation > span{
        font-family: Open Sans;
        font-size: 14.49px;
        text-align: justify;
        text-justify: auto;
        font-weight: 300;
    }

Answer (score 1):

The text you are referring to ("Conforme o art. 43...") is inside a `span` tag that has an inline style `style="font-weight: bold,"`.

An inline style like this will override every CSS rule that you define in an external style sheet or in a `<style>` tag inside the header of your page, so you need to

...either erase this style tag in the HTML code (if it's actually there), or

...if it's not there, it's inserted via javascript. So you need to find out which javascript inserts this code into the HTML code and erase or deactivate that code.

EDIT / Additional note: The code of the answer which you just accepted will apply that CSS rule either to *all* direct children elements of *any* div or (second option) even apply it to *all*  elements in your page. I strongly doubt that you want either of this, since most likely your pages will consist of more than what you showed us...

Comment: I don't have your HTML code, and I don't know what your Javascript code looks like, so I can't. I just told you the possible causes and where to look...

Comment: It's fine! It seems like the other guy correct the previous mistake!